# How to config webpack for universal app react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, config, server-side-rendering

I have an application SPA working correctly, then I need to change the meta tag in order to share the site with og:meta. After a lot of researches, I know that I need to render my content into the server, so my application will be a universal application (server + client renders). I tried to create a simple server, then added a bit code to `webpack config`. But I got stuck in there. Here is my webpage config:

webpack.config.dev.js

```
'use strict';

const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CaseSensitivePathsPlugin = require('case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin');
const InterpolateHtmlPlugin = require('react-dev-utils/InterpolateHtmlPlugin');
const WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin = require('react-dev-utils/WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin');
const ModuleScopePlugin = require('react-dev-utils/ModuleScopePlugin');
const ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin = require('fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin');
const getClientEnvironment = require('./env');
const paths = require('./paths');
const TsconfigPathsPlugin = require('tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin');

// Webpack uses `publicPath` to determine where the app is being served from.
// In development, we always serve from the root. This makes config easier.
const publicPath = '/';
// `publicUrl` is just like `publicPath`, but we will provide it to our app
// as %PUBLIC_URL% in `index.html` and `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` in JavaScript.
// Omit trailing slash as %PUBLIC_PATH%/xyz looks better than %PUBLIC_PATH%xyz.
const publicUrl = '';

const env = getClientEnvironment(publicUrl);


const client = {
  devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
  entry: [
    require.resolve('./polyfills'),
    require.resolve('react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient'),
    paths.appIndexJs,
  ],
  output: {
    pathinfo: true,
    filename: 'static/js/bundle.js',
    chunkFilename: 'static/js/[name].chunk.js',
    publicPath: publicPath,
    devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: info =>
      path.resolve(info.absoluteResourcePath).replace(/\\/g, '/'),
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: ['node_modules', paths.appNodeModules].concat(
      process.env.NODE_PATH.split(path.delimiter).filter(Boolean)
    ),
    extensions: [
      '.mjs',
      '.web.ts',
      '.ts',
      '.web.tsx',
      '.tsx',
      '.web.js',
      '.js',
      '.json',
      '.web.jsx',
      '.jsx',
    ],
    alias: {
      'react-native': 'react-native-web',
    },
    plugins: [
      new ModuleScopePlugin(paths.appSrc, [paths.appPackageJson]),
      new TsconfigPathsPlugin({ configFile: paths.appTsConfig }),
    ],
  },
  module: {
    strictExportPresence: true,
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx|mjs)$/,
        loader: require.resolve('source-map-loader'),
        enforce: 'pre',
        include: paths.appSrc,
      },
      {
        oneOf: [
          {
            test: [/\.bmp$/, /\.gif$/, /\.jpe?g$/, /\.png$/],
            loader: require.resolve('url-loader'),
            options: {
              limit: 10000,
              name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
            },
          },
          {
            test: /\.(js|jsx|mjs)$/,
            include: paths.appSrc,
            loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
            options: {

              compact: true,
            },
          },

          {
            test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
            include: paths.appSrc,
            use: [
              {
                loader: require.resolve('ts-loader'),
                options: {
                  // disable type checker - we will use it in fork plugin
                  transpileOnly: true,
                },
              },
            ],
          },
          {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: [
              require.resolve('style-loader'),
              {
                loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
                options: {
                  importLoaders: 1,
                },
              },
              {
                loader: require.resolve('postcss-loader'),
                options: {
                  ident: 'postcss',
                  plugins: () => [
                    require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes'),
                    autoprefixer({
                      browsers: [
                        '>1%',
                        'last 4 versions',
                        'Firefox ESR',
                        'not ie < 9', // React doesn't support IE8 anyway
                      ],
                      flexbox: 'no-2009',
                    }),
                  ],
                },
              },
            ],
          },
          {
            exclude: [/\.(js|jsx|mjs)$/, /\.html$/, /\.json$/],
            loader: require.resolve('file-loader'),
            options: {
              name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new InterpolateHtmlPlugin(env.raw),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      inject: true,
      template: paths.appHtml,
    }),
    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin(env.stringified),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new CaseSensitivePathsPlugin(),
    new WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin(paths.appNodeModules),
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/),
    new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin({
      async: false,
      watch: paths.appSrc,
      tsconfig: paths.appTsConfig,
      tslint: paths.appTsLint,
    }),
  ],
  node: {
    dgram: 'empty',
    fs: 'empty',
    net: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty',
    child_process: 'empty',
  },
  performance: {
    hints: false,
  },
}


/* i add a bit code to config server rendering */
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

const server = {
  target: 'node',
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  entry: [
    paths.appServerJs,
  ],
  output: {
    pathinfo: true,
    filename: 'static/js/bundle.js',
    chunkFilename: 'static/js/[name].chunk.js',
    publicPath: publicPath,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx|mjs)$/,
        loader: require.resolve('source-map-loader'),
        enforce: 'pre',
        include: paths.appSrc,
      },
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx|mjs)$/,
        include: paths.appSrc,
        loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
        options: {

          compact: true,
        },
      },

      // Compile .tsx?
      {
        test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
        include: paths.appSrc,
        use: [
          {
            loader: require.resolve('ts-loader'),
            options: {
              // disable type checker - we will use it in fork plugin
              transpileOnly: true,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new InterpolateHtmlPlugin(env.raw),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      inject: true,
      template: paths.appHtml,
    }),
  ],
}
module.exports = [client, server]
```

server.tsx

```
import express from 'express';

const port = 3000;
const server = express();

server.use(express.static('dist'));

server.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send("hello world");
})

server.listen(3000, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!'));
```

`const client` works correctly.

But when I try `module.exports = [client, server]` I got this error 
`Cannot read property 'publicPath' of undefined.`

Is my config correct? Does anyone have some example config?

Comment: I think webpack expects a single object export with the config, not an array..

Comment: i found the config in this article: https://medium.com/@muthuks/creating-a-server-bundle-with-webpack-for-universal-rendering-50bf0b71af79, i have tried too ```module.exports = server ``` but nothing works

Comment: Ah nice, didn't know that.. Maybe it uses an older version of webpack?

Comment: hm, ya, you're right, I didn't notice that. He used webpack 2 instead of 4 like me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see publicPath being defined anywhere. Might it be this?

Comment: Sorry, It was my mistake. When i deleted the comment in the code, I've also deleted it. I edited my code.